# ASP.NET WebAPI request never completes - but only when the debugger is attached

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015

My ASP.NET WebAPI + AngularJS app runs when I do CTRL + F5 to start without debugging. But as soon as I start the debugger in Visual Studio one of the HTTP calls fails to come back.

- I tried switching from IIS Express to straight IIS and same behaviour occurs
- Tried different browsers
- Tried restarting Visual Studio, the machine and cleaning the solution
- Observed that it only appears to be affecting one method in particular
- Observed that when debugger is on and the call is made the breakpoint in the method (GetWords) is hit and so far as Visual Studio is concerned the data has been sent back.
- Observed Fiddler4 to see Result column says "-" and Body column says "-1" - no data comes back into the Inspectors tab in Fiddler4, but I can see my request and compared to my other requests it looks fine.

When debugger not attached, everything is fine and words are sent back. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who spends hours trying to figure this out...

- Payload size - debugger can't handle large JSON payloads